# Connect StoryBoard Button with Programmatically build UITabBarController

Tags: ios, swift3, xcode8, ios10

i build two project

1. Story Board -> Login Screen
2. Programmatically -> UITabBarController

both are different Projects but managed With MVC structure
now i want to connect StoryBoard Button with Programmatically build UITabBarController 
Please Help me to solve this Problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To create a view controller:

```
UIViewController * vc = [[UIViewController alloc] init];
```

To call a view controller (must be called from within another viewcontroller):

```
[self presentViewController:vc animated:YES completion:nil];
```

For one, use nil rather than null.

Loading a view controller from the storyboard:

```
NSString * storyboardName = @"MainStoryboard"; 
UIStoryboard *storyboard = [UIStoryboard storyboardWithName:storyboardName bundle: nil];
UIViewController * vc = [storyboard instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"IDENTIFIER_OF_YOUR_VIEWCONTROLLER"];
[self presentViewController:vc animated:YES completion:nil];
```

Identifier of your view controller is either equal to the class name of your view controller, or a Storyboard ID that you can assign in the identity inspector of your storyboard.